# Edit Item in Bottom Toolbar Xcode and Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Navigation Controller. I want to put the edit button on the bottom in the toolbar instead of in the top navigation bar.

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

The problem I have is that when I add the edit button to the Bottom Toolbar. like this:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    // Delete the row from the data source
    [self.christmasGifts removeGiftAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
}   
}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];

//Do not let the user add if the app is in edit mode.
if(editing)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
else
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
 }
```

And then link the edit button setEditing: in the toolbar it does not show a done button like the Edit button in the top navigation. it just stays the same.

But you can delete an item, but you cannot reset the state to normal again with the bottom button.

I need to be able to go back to the previous controller from this Navigation Controller. but the edit button hides the back button.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit.

I know I can by code add the toolbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                           initWithTitle:@"Edit"
                           style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                           target:self
                           action:@selector(setEditing:)];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:70/255.0f green:155/255.0f blue:19/255.0f alpha:1.0]];

NSArray *arrBtns = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:editButton,anotherButton, nil];
self.toolbarItems = arrBtns;
```

and

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];
```

or even

```
  UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 500, 400, 40)];
  [self.tableView addSubview:toolBar];
```

Comment: Are you using `XIB`s for creating ToolBar?

Comment: I have a storyboard. I made the bottom toolbar and item in the builder. But you can use [self.tableView addSubview:toolBar]; to set the toolbar and see my edit in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `ViewController.h`, declare (and connect them in `XIB`)

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *toolbarbutton;

- (IBAction)toolbarbuttonTouched:(id)sender; // Connect with UIBarButtonItem in XIB
```

In your `ViewController.m`, paste down the following function.

```
- (IBAction)toolbarbuttonTouched:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.toolbarbutton.title isEqualToString:@"Edit"])
    {
        [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        self.toolbarbutton.title = @"Done";
    }
    else
    {
        [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        self.toolbarbutton.title = @"Edit";
    }
}
```

And you are all set to go.

**Points**

1. Your `UIBarButtonItem`'s initial value for property `title` must be
   set to "Edit"
2. Code for `editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` should
   be working perfectly

## EDIT

**You don't need the following code:**

`self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;`

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {

[super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
[self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];

//Do not let the user add if the app is in edit mode.
if(editing)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
else
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
 }
```

Let me know, If it works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this more simply by using UIViewController's [editButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/editButtonItem) method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Place table view Edit button in toolbar, after existing buttons.
    NSMutableArray *items = [self.toolbarItems mutableCopy];
    [items addObject:self.editButtonItem];
    [self setToolbarItems:items animated:YES];
}
```

This gets the existing array of toolbar buttons (if any) and makes a mutable copy of the array so it can be changed. It then adds UIViewController's built-in Edit button to the toolbar.

The result is a functioning Edit/Done toolbar button that toggles Edit mode on and off, without having to write your own action method to handle that.